# How to use bcp command to import data in excel file into table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bcp

Please help me to solve this problem I got stuck to import excel data into table I am getting error that I mentioned in image file.Please assist me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use openrowset instead?

Comment: I want to do it on bcp command only..

Answer (score 1):

If you use openrowset, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * INTO StagingTableLeadSource
                FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'EXCEL 12.0;Database=D:\LeadSource.xls;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1','SELECT *  FROM [lead_source$]')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can copy-paste data from en excel-sheet to an SQL-table by doing so:

1. Select the data in excel and press Ctrl + C
2. Select the data in Excel and press Ctrl + C
3. In SQL Server Management Studio right click the table and choose Edit Top 200 Rows
4. Scroll to the bottom and select the entire empty row by clicking on the row header
5. Paste the data by pressing Ctrl + V