How to bulk Insert a specific tab from a xlsx file into SQL Server?
I want to use a Bulk Insert function to upload the data from two different tabs in the same .xlsx file.
I created an empty table with column names that match the table from the first tab in the Excel file. In the Bulk Insert section, I then use the file path to access the Excel file. I feel like I'm missing one line of code that will instruct SQL which Excel tab to pull (let's call if GotvShiftsTab):
DROP TABLE #GotvShifts

CREATE TABLE #GotvShifts 
(
    VANID            varchar(100),
    contact_name     varchar(100),
    signup_date      varchar(100),
    status_          varchar(100),
    role_            varchar(100),
    event_name       varchar(100),
    event_type       varchar(100),
    event_date       varchar(100),
    shift_start_time varchar(100),
    shift_end_time   varchar(100),
    location_name    varchar(100),
    recruited_by     varchar(100)
)

BULK INSERT #GotvShifts
FROM '\na2-fs1\DCDATA6\Cases\Active\47758 – Meza v Coty\Team Member Folders\AS\data_exam_q1_datasets.xlsx'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,Rowterminator='\n')


try openrowset instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691124/how-to-use-bcp-command-to-import-data-in-excel-file-into-table

On second thoughts don't use OPENROWSET. Using  the ACE provider is not supported by Microsoft, it works most of the time but it's not designed for a server application. Use Import/Export Wizard in SSMS or a similar tool.

Is this a one-off or do you need it to be repeatable. If one-off have you thought of using SSMS, right click database, select Database tasks->Import Data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/get-started-with-this-simple-example-of-the-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16. Also from this article is this example: SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Data Source=C:\Temp\Data.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Sheet1$];
GO
